# Laravel 10 - Login y setear base de datos en conexion

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, login

Tengo un formulario el cual tiene 3 campos, `Usuario`, `Password` y `Espacio_trabajo`.
Lo que necesito hacer, es un login, el cual primero compruebe que una base de datos exista en el servidor mysql, luego setear esa base de datos en la configuracion del sistema para que tome esa por defecto y no la configurada en la variable de entorno `DB_DATABASE` y que esta perdurecada vez que se acceda a un controlador, vista, modelo, etc.

Luego que queda configurada utilizable, se accede a la tabla usuario dentro de esa base y se realiza el login

La idea de esto es porque estamos creando un sistema el cual cada usuario tiene su base de datos y estas se crean de forma dinamica, entonces me complica un poco esa parte.

Trate utilizando un metodo, el cual si me permite hacer estos pasos, pero solo hasta que valido que el usuario exista y hace el login, pero al cambiar de ruta, vuelve nuevamente a la base seteada en `DB_DATABASE`

Este es mi login que trate de realizar los pasos que indico:

```
public function login(Request $request) {

        $loginRequest = $request->only(["Espacio_trabajo", "Usuario", "Password"]);
        
        $databaseExists = DB::select(
            "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = ?", [ $loginRequest["Espacio_trabajo"] ]
        );
        // Validar existe Espacio de Trabajo
        if (!$databaseExists) throw ValidationException::withMessages(["loginError" => "Espacio de Trabajo no existe"]);

        // Setear Espacio de Trabajo en el sistema
        config(['database.default' => "mysql"]);
        config(["database.connections.mysql.database" => $loginRequest["Espacio_trabajo"]]);
        
        // Reconectar
        DB::purge('mysql');
        DB::reconnect('mysql');

        // Comprobar usuario
        $remember = $request->filled("remember");
        $usuario = Usuario::where('Usuario', $loginRequest["Usuario"])
                            ->where('Password', md5($loginRequest["Password"]))
                            ->first();

        if (!$usuario) throw ValidationException::withMessages(["loginError" => "Usuario o contraseña inválidos"]);

        // Realizar login
        Auth::login($usuario, $remember);
        // Variables de Sesion personalizados
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $request->session()->put('pTotal', 'pTotal Web');
        $request->session()->put('Espacio_trabajo', $loginRequest["Espacio_trabajo"]);

        //if ($usuario->rol->Id == 1) return redirect()->intended( route('admin.dashboard.index') );

        return redirect()->intended( route('dashboard.index') );

    }
```

Tambien trate creando una variable de sesion y en el archivo public/index.php hacer una funcion pequeña para cambiar esa variable de entorno de forma dinamica, pero tampoco funciono:

```
// Cambiar espacio de trabajo
$espacioTrabajo = $_SESSION['Espacio_trabajo'] ?? null;

if ($espacioTrabajo && env('DB_DATABASE') !== $espacioTrabajo) {
    putenv("DB_DATABASE=sisf_crm_1234");
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar con esto que me tiene estancado y se los agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre una forma para lo que necesito, y espero les ayude a muchos que buscan mas o menos lo mismo.

En mi controlador de login, cree una funcion el cual recibe el request del formulario y realiza el login.

```
public function login(Request $request) {

        $loginRequest = $request->only(["Espacio_trabajo", "Usuario", "Password"]);

        $databaseExists = DB::select(
            "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = ?", [ $loginRequest["Espacio_trabajo"] ]
        );
        // Validar existe Espacio de Trabajo
        if (!$databaseExists) throw ValidationException::withMessages(["loginError" => "Espacio de Trabajo no existe"]);

        // Setear Espacio de Trabajo en el sistema
        config([ "database.connections.system_mysql.database" => $loginRequest["Espacio_trabajo"] ]);
        // Reconectar
        DB::purge('system_mysql');
        DB::reconnect('system_mysql');
        
        // Comprobar usuario
        $remember = $request->filled("remember");
        $usuario = Usuario::where('Usuario', $loginRequest["Usuario"])
                            ->where('Password', md5($loginRequest["Password"]))
                            ->first();

        if (!$usuario) throw ValidationException::withMessages(["loginError" => "Usuario o contraseña inválidos"]);

        // Realizar login
        Auth::login($usuario, $remember);
        // Variables de Sesion personalizados
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $request->session()->put('Espacio_trabajo', $loginRequest["Espacio_trabajo"]);

        return redirect()->intended( route('dashboard.index') );

    }
```

En resumen, lo primero que hago en el request `Espacio_trabajo` realizo una query generica, la cual consulta si la base de datos existe, caso contrario, retorna al formulario indicando error.

En caso que si exista, en cualquier conexion ya creada en "database/config.php" seteo la base de datos por defecto, por la que esta en el campo `Espacio_trabajo`.
luego 'elimino' y vuelvo a reconectarme, para que asi tome el nuevo valor agregado.

Con esto, realizo los pasos del login y antes de enviar a la ruta por defecto, creo una variable de session (la pueden nombrar como quieran) y le asignan el valor de que viene en `Espacio_trabajo` (ojo que `Espacio_trabajo` es el campo que viene del formulario y la que uno envia con el nombre de la base de datos que quiera usar. Este campo puede tener el nombre que ustedes quieran)

Seguido, ir a la ruta de archivo `vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php` y abrirlo.

Buscar la función `make` y agregar esta linea dentro:

```
if ( session('Espacio_trabajo') && $config["database"] != session('Espacio_trabajo') ) {
            // Setear Espacio de Trabajo en el sistema
            $config["database"] = session('Espacio_trabajo');
        }
```

Con esto, podran cambiar la base de datos con la que se accede de forma dinamica a traves de la variable de sesion. Aqui doy un ejemplo de como quedaria:

```
public function make(array $config, $name = null)
    {
        $config = $this->parseConfig($config, $name);

        //TODO Comprobar que se aplique a todos los modelos
        if ( session('Espacio_trabajo') && $config["database"] != session('Espacio_trabajo') ) {
            // Setear Espacio de Trabajo en el sistema
            $config["database"] = session('Espacio_trabajo');
        }

        if (isset($config['read'])) {
            return $this->createReadWriteConnection($config);
        }

        return $this->createSingleConnection($config);
    }
```

Ojo, que aqui puedes encriptar la informacion que lleva la sesion con el nombre de la base de datos para mayor seguridad y luego desencriptarla en este apartado.

Espero a alguien le sirva.